# How to use subplot to plot nrows=12,ncols=2

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to use subplots to plot 12x2(rowsxcolumns). However, my code seems to be plotting all the 12 graphs on the same figure 12 times. I have attached my code below, if someone can help me understand where I am going wrong, it would really help me.
Note : I am reading the data from two different folders. The first column corresponds to the plots from the first file of the folder and the second column to the second file.
I want to plot 1st data from 1st file and 2nd file in positions [0,0] and [0,1] respectively. I want to repeat this for all 12 files. [image]

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(12, 2,figsize=(20,80))
for file in files: # reading data from 1st file
        with open(file,"r") as f_in: 
            reader=csv.reader(f_in)
            next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                try:
                    float_1,float_2=float(line[0]),float(line[1])
                    xData.append(float_1)
                    yData.append(float_2)
                except ValueError:
                    continue                     
        for i in range(12):
            axs[i,0].plot(xData,yData)
        xData=[]
        yData=[]                            
for file in files1:
    with open(file,"r") as f_in: 
        reader=csv.reader(f_in)
        next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            try:
                float_1,float_2=float(line[0]),float(line[1])
                xData1.append(float_1)
                yData1.append(float_2)
            except ValueError:
                continue
    for i in range(12):
        axs[i, 1].plot(xData1, yData1)            
    xData1=[]
    yData1=[]
```

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about the subplot addressing itself. However, the code appears to be poorly organized. For example, `xData=[]` is after `xData.append(float_1)`. Given the OP, this shouldn't even run, so something is missing. There's not sample data to test. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are plotting on all plots for each file `axs[i,0].plot(xData,yData)` and `axs[i,1].plot(xData1,yData1)` as you have a loop (`for i in range(12)`) within a loop (`for file in files1`).

Here is a quick fix of this error in your code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(12, 2,figsize=(20,80))
i = 0
for file in files: # reading data from 1st file
        with open(file,"r") as f_in: 
            reader=csv.reader(f_in)
            next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                try:
                    float_1,float_2=float(line[0]),float(line[1])
                    xData.append(float_1)
                    yData.append(float_2)
                except ValueError:
                    continue                     
        
        axs[i,0].plot(xData,yData)
        i+=1
        xData=[]
        yData=[]
i = 0
for file in files1:
    with open(file,"r") as f_in: 
        reader=csv.reader(f_in)
        next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            try:
                float_1,float_2=float(line[0]),float(line[1])
                xData1.append(float_1)
                yData1.append(float_2)
            except ValueError:
                continue
    axs[i, 1].plot(xData1, yData1)  
    i+=1
    xData1=[]
    yData1=[]
```

**NB. of course the number of files should not exceed 12, or you will have an IndexError**

*NB.2 there are much better ways to organize the code, the ideal might be to create a function that takes the file and an axes object as argument and plots the file's data on this axis. Then you can iterate over the axes.*